# Behat, JUnit and Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, junit, behat

I'm going a little insane trying to interpret Behat results as JUnit reports.

I'm using an ant build in order to generate tests results, this is how it is invoked:

```
<target name="behat" description="Run Behat Scenarios">
    <exec executable="php">
        <arg value="vendor/behat/behat/bin/behat" />
        <arg value="--format" />
        <arg value="pretty" />
        <arg value="--out" />
        <arg value="std" />
        <arg value="--format" />
        <arg value="junit" />
        <arg value="--out" />
        <arg value="${basedir}/build/logs/" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

This is the console output from Jenkins:

```
INFO: Processing JUnit
INFO: [JUnit] - 1 test report file(s) were found with the pattern 'build/logs/default.xml' relative to '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Web-Analysis' for the testing framework 'JUnit'.
WARNING: The file '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Web-Analysis/build/logs/default.xml' is an invalid file.
WARNING: At line 4 of file:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Web-Analysis/build/logs/default.xml:cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'status' is not allowed to appear in element 'testcase'.
WARNING: At line 5 of file:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Web-Analysis/build/logs/default.xml:cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'status' is not allowed to appear in element 'testcase'.
ERROR: The plugin hasn't been performed correctly: The result file '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Web-Analysis/build/logs/default.xml' for the metric 'JUnit' is not valid. The result file has been skipped.
```

And this is the generated JUnit file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites name="default">
  <testsuite name="Testing" tests="2" skipped="0" failures="0" errors="0" time="0">
    <testcase name="Home Page" status="passed" time="0"></testcase>
    <testcase name="Dashboard is locked to guests" status="passed" time="0"></testcase>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

I've seen a few questions related to it, but couldn't really find an answer on how to solve this. Any help would be appreciated, and I'd be happy to give more details if needed! I'm using Behat 3.5.0 if that helps.

--edit
Just adding behat.yml and console output

```
default:
    gherkin:
        cache: ~
    extensions:
        Laracasts\Behat\ServiceContainer\BehatExtension: ~
        Behat\MinkExtension\ServiceContainer\MinkExtension:
            default_session: laravel
            laravel: ~



behat:
     [exec] Feature: Testing
     [exec]     In order to learn Behat
     [exec]     As a developer
     [exec]     I want to learn how to install and create features
     [exec] 
     [exec]   Scenario: Home Page                  # features/example.feature:6
     [exec]     Given I am on the homepage         # FeatureContext::iAmOnHomepage()
     [exec]     Then I should see "Audio" # FeatureContext::assertPageContainsText()
     [exec] 
     [exec]   Scenario: Dashboard is locked to guests # features/example.feature:10
     [exec]     When I go to "admin"                  # FeatureContext::visit()
     [exec]     Then the url should match "login"     # FeatureContext::assertUrlRegExp()
     [exec]     And I can do something with Laravel   # FeatureContext::iCanDoSomethingWithLaravel()
     [exec] 
     [exec] 2 scenarios (2 passed)
     [exec] 5 steps (5 passed)
     [exec] 0m0.14s (22.99Mb)
```

Comment: The issue is that the output file isn't valid according to JUnit/Jenkins. My advice would be to try to find how it should look like and check the documentation of Behat to see how you can create such an output.

Comment: Totally understood the problem the same way! Kind of weird when generating the output through the junit option of behat - so I figured there might be a mistake in my way of generating it. I followed the documentation the best I could but couldn't find the answer. My best bet at the moment is using xsltproc to refactor the report (I might even have to do it to use multiple test suits), but if I can avoid that step I'll gladly do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had this problem after upgrading Jenkins xUnit plugin to 2.2.3 (from 2.0.0), downgrading to 2.0.0 "solved" the problem.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot! I was getting insane.